# libreoffice themes in elementary os problem?

Tags: release-hera, settings, themes, icons, libreoffice

How do you get libreoffice writer to look good, I got the elementary OS style sheet and icons but it looks pretty ordinary, the galaxy icon set is an improvement but still looks ugly.

Any help?

Thx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can select any other UI from the menus:

> view -> user interface

If you're more of a ribborn UI style, the select the tabbed UI, on the other hand I just selected the white background under tools -> options -> customization to have a more "cleaner" buttons layout.

[image: My libreoffice]